# Does auto-acknowledge mean no-ack?

Tags: activemq-classic

I am wondering for auto-acknowledge , does it mean : when the server does not receive acknowledge from consumer, it will delete the message and will not send again.

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveMQ broker will not delete messages without an acknowledge. If a message is read by a client and there is no acknowledge for that message, the message will be available on the queue once that client disconnects.

Auto acknowledge is simply a client setting to make that client automatically acknowledge messages as it reads them. If you want more control, you should not relay on auto ack.